# Specifying cocoa pods per Xcode target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I wanted to use a specific podfile per target in my Xcode project.

In my Xcode project I have four targets:

- production
- preview
- staging
- dev

Production preview and staging I want to use Podfile which declares dependencies the same and for a private cocoa pod I want to use a specific tag for release version.

But in dev I would like to use a local directory or the dev branch of the cocoa pod.

How would I do that? Would I declare a second podfile with different dependencies?

Edit:
Using the answer.

```
target :MyProject-Dev, :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj' # Or if you have multiple      implicit project dependencies, change here.
    pod 'privatepod' :git => "<giturl>", :branch => 'dev'

    link_with 'MyProjectDevTarget' # Your Xcode Project target.
end

target :MyProject-Staging, :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj' # Or if you have multiple implicit project dependencies, change here.
    pod 'privatepod' :git => "<giturl>", :tag => '1.0.9'

    link_with 'MyProjectStagingTarget'
end
```

I run into an issue where pod update complains about multiple dependencies with different sources for 'privatepod'

Answer (score 0):

You need only single Podfile, but declare exclusive Podfile-Target(s) to link against multiple Xcode Project targets. For example your Podfile may look like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.1'

workspace 'MyProject'
xcodeproj 'MyProject/MyProject'

############################
# Dev Exclusive Target
############################

target :MyProject-Dev, :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj' # Or if you have multiple implicit project dependencies, change here.

    pod AFNetworking
    # More pods here.

    link_with 'MyProjectDevTarget' # Your Xcode Project target.
end

############################
# Staging Exclusive Target
############################

target :MyProject-Staging, :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj' # Or if you have multiple implicit project dependencies, change here.

    pod SomeDifferentPod

    link_with 'MyProjectStagingTarget'
end
```

"MyProject-Dev" and "MyProject-Staging" are Podfile targets which scopes what Pods will be compiled into single library (.a file) and link against specified Xcode Project target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This organization makes sense but it doesnt solve my problem. See updated question.